# Function of heat in thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics

Is heat in isothermal process completely converted into work, or is it just supplied to maintain thermal equilibrium?

Comment: A little reading on the Second Law of Thermodynamics should give you a clue as to whether you can realistically get complete heat conversion to work.

Answer (score 2):

If the system is an ideal gas, during a reversible isothermal expansion thermal equilibrium is maintained AND heat is completely converted to work. Per the first law there is no change in internal energy since $\Delta U=Q-W$. But the process must be reversible.

If your question concerns some other type of system, please specify what it is.

Hope this helps

Comment: This is assuming, of course, that internal energy is a function of temperature only, which is not a valid assumption is most cases.

Comment: My answer was based on an isothermal expansion of an ideal gas. See my revision to clarify.